# What do I need to work with a Visual Studio .dtproj file?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis

I have a .sln file created in Visual Studio 2010:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 11.00
# Visual Studio 2010
```

This has a single Project which is a .dtproj file. The header of this file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DeploymentModel>Project</DeploymentModel>
  <ProductVersion>11.0.2100.60</ProductVersion>
  <SchemaVersion>9.0.1.0</SchemaVersion>
```

I have VS 2010 Professional installed, but when I try to open this solution I get an error that the project type is not supported.

This machine also has VS2008, VS2012, and SQL Server 2008R2 with the BI Dev Studio.

What am I missing?  How can I get support for this .dtproj project type?

Comment: Do you have BIDS (SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio and Integration Services installed?

Comment: Yes, that's the BI Dev studio mentioned above.  That couldn't open it either.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the project extension for this purpose.
Here is the download link from marketplace.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects

After that you need to restart the visual studio and you should be open up the project without any issue.

Comment: +1 The download above (SSIS v3.15) worked for me in VS2019 (v16.11.2 Sept 2021)
also see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54707335/ssdt-for-visual-studio-2019

Answer (score 0):

Looks like MS has a solution for you (from Microsoft Support):

To resolve the issue in which you cannot open the project in SQL Server BIDS after you upgrade the project, follow these steps:

- Create a new project that has the same name as the original BI project in a different directory by using SQL Server BIDS.
- Add all relevant project items from the upgraded BI project folder. For example, for an Analysis Services project, add the .ds and .dsv files. For a Reporting Services project, add the .rds and .rdl files.
- Save and then open the new BI project.

You can read more about it [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983332).