# SSDT for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, visual-studio-2019

I have found the installer for the VS2017 version [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017), but is there one for the 2019 preview version?

Comment: "https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server-Integration-Services/New-Delivery-Model-for-SQL-Server-Data-Tools-in-Visual-Studio/ba-p/479289" --> "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects&ssr=false#overview" --> This is a free preview version 3.0 of SSIS tools for Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 13):

**SQL Server Reporting Services and SQL Server Analysis Services (SSRS, SSDT, SSAS, MSAS):**
Support for these project types is provided through two extensions in the Visual Studio Gallery: [Microsoft Analysis Services Modeling Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftAnalysisServicesModelingProjects) and [Microsoft Reporting Services Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio). SSDT support is also included with the Data Storage and Processing workload in Visual Studio 2019.

**SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS):**
Support for Visual Studio 2019 is coming soon. Get latest news from the [SQL Server Data Tools Team Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ssdt/).

*the info source is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(VS.ReviewProjectAndSolutionChangesDialog.Upgrade)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019).

Comment: April 19, 2017 => Latest news?

Comment: There is also important to switch to english language pack, because VS searches components in relevant language.

Comment: The SQL project might show as incompatible even after installing this extension. Right click the project and reload.
My setup: rptproj with extension version 2.6.3. I did a reboot after the installation; not sure whether that did anything.

Comment: For SSRS report project (rptproj) installing Microsoft Reporting Services Projects worked for VS2019

Answer (score 11):

**April 15th, 2019 Release of SQL Server Integration Services Projects (Version 3.0 Preview):**

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects&ssr=false#overview

Update: opened an existing dtproj successfully in Visual Studio 2019, and so far, Script Components have kept their code in-between saves

**Note:**
For users who are worried about downloading Visual Studio Community Edition for commercial use.

The EULA of VS 2019 community edition has a specific section that allows enterprise users to use it for the SSDT workload. See https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/license-terms/mlt031819/.

> Any number of your users may use the software only for Microsoft SQL
> Server development when using the SQL Server Data Tools or the
> extensions “Microsoft Analysis Services Projects”, “Microsoft
> Reporting Services Projects”, or “SQL Server Integration Services
> Projects” to develop Microsoft SQL Server database projects or
> Analysis Services, Reporting Services, Power BI Report Server, or
> Integration Services projects.

Comment: You can also now find the SSIS extension inside Visual Studio by entering:   "SQL Server Integration Services Projects"  into the extensions dialog search box.

Comment: Thank you, this is the missing piece! (along w/ the aforementioned extensions listed in the official docs.) Note that while you you can find it in the extensions search, it's still an external .exe download, and must have VS closed to install.

Comment: Recommend not using. It's full of bugs (Feb 2020). It does stuff like randomly deletes all your connections, is painfully slow and wrecks deployments. I would suggest MS haven't even tested it and they are relying on the community to update them, but updates are few and far between. Stick with 2017 probably for a couple of years.

Answer (score 5):

In the Visual Studio 2019 installer make sure you've selected the Data Storage and Processing payload. It will install the latest version of SSDT into your Visual Studio 2019 installation:

[image]

Afterward, it shows up here (for me):

[image]

Comment: Huh I have done that, but the SSDT folder does not show up inside my VS2019 directory.

Comment: If you install this way, this may install some bits but you are still unable to open any SSRS or SSIS packages as it says they are unsupported. According to the comment here from MSFT they will be releasing a preview release during April: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/400935/ssis-project-will-not-open-in-vs-2019-preview.html

Comment: Sadly, the documentation for the changes to how SSIS is handled in VS 2019 isn't really working. You must still download the 400mb extension and install it (reboot required). It's in preview currently, but i've confirmed i'm able to open my previous SSIS projects. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects&ssr=false#overview

Comment: I had to open VS, go to Extensions --> Manage Extensions, then search for Microsoft Reporting Projects or something, close VS, install that, then was good.

Answer (score 2):

it is showing on the same page for which you gave the link.. but it seems not yet released  by ms itself..

[image]

best way is to raise a ticket with ms if you have support agreement ..

Comment: I think that website has a bug - it shows the same page for every selected version.

Comment: if you select 2014 it shows a message that latest version is shown..

Comment: The requested page is not available for SQL Server 2014. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page is available for.

Comment: Even after release date of VS2019 still no SSDT, and yes page is bugged, they will just show the one for SSDT 2017 anyway...