# Visual Studio 2019 claims most SSAS projects within my solution are "incompatible"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, ssas-tabular

We have developed several SSAS tabular models within Visual Studio over the years.

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 on a "clean" machine.
When I open a particular solution, I get "incompatible" on most models.

Yet another developer in our team can open the solution in Visual Studio 2019 as well, without problem.
He has Visual Studio 2012 and 2017 installed as well as 2019.

The two models I can open have their compatibility levels "SQL Server 2016 RTM (1200)".
But checking on my colleague's machine, the others have the same compatibility levels.

I compared the projects ".smproj" and cannot spot any significant difference.
I also tried to text compare the ".bim" files and the header sections seem very similar too.

Any idea what I could check?

Eric

PS: we have another solution that I can open without problem and see all projects...

Comment: https://tomaztsql.wordpress.com/2019/11/03/installing-ssis-ssrs-and-ssas-with-visual-studio-2019/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54707335/ssdt-for-visual-studio-2019

Comment: Thanks but I had already installed these. two out of about 15 Tabular models did open properly. This is what made all this weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the workaround was to delete the .suo file hidden within the .vs hidden folder.

Although the problem description is different, the fix exposed [here](https://www.howtosolutions.net/2013/02/solving-project-file-error-could-not-find-part-of-the-path-with-visual-studio/) actually worked