# How to run .dtProj on Visual Studio 2019 or 2022

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project which is related to SQL Migrations and its extension is `dtProj`

When I am opening it in Visual Studio 2019 it is saying (incompatible)

And a link opens in browser automatically saying that

ERROR : The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=660952&projecttype=159641D6-6404-4A2A-AE62-294DE0FE8301

Earlier I was using 2022 for my personal development but I installed Visual Studio 2019 now to see if it works but it did not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I need to work with a Visual Studio .dtproj file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691898/what-do-i-need-to-work-with-a-visual-studio-dtproj-file)

Comment: No , it did not , I have installed that extension